# Умножение многочленов

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Необходимо переопределить операцию умножения для класса полином. сам полином задается массивом коэффициентов и может быть произвольной длины. все время проблемы с выходом индекса за границы массива. Такое ощущение, что все должно быть гораздо проще. но проще не выходит.
Заранее спасибо

```
public class Polynom
{
    public int[] coefficients;

    public Polynom(params int[] coefficients)
    {
        this.coefficients = coefficients;
    }

    public static Polynom operator * (Polynom polynom1, Polynom polynom2)
    {
        int size = polynom1.coefficients.Length + polynom2.coefficients.Length;
        int[] multiplyCoefficients = new int[size - 1];

        int a = polynom1.coefficients.Length;
        int b = polynom2.coefficients.Length;
        int c = multiplyCoefficients.Length;

        if (a>= b)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<multiplyCoefficients.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((i >= 0) && (i < b))
                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        multiplyCoefficients[i] += polynom1.coefficients[j] * polynom2.coefficients[i - j];
                    }

                if ((i >= b) && (i < a))
                    for (int j = b; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        multiplyCoefficients[i] += polynom1.coefficients[j] * polynom2.coefficients[i - j];
                    }

                if ((i >= a) && (i < c))
                    for (int j = a; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        multiplyCoefficients[i] += polynom1.coefficients[j] * polynom2.coefficients[i - j];
                    }
            }
         }
            return new Polynom(multiplyCoefficients);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого, целая куча циклов и ветвлений...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При перемножении старших членов получится член степени `n1 + n2`, где `n1` и `n2` — степени многочленов-множителей. С учетом наличия свободного члена (со степенью 0) нам потребуется `(n1 - 1) + (n2 - 1) + 1 = n1 + n2 - 1` ячеек.

Воспользуемся тем, что при создании массива `int[]` он будет инициализирован нулями. Теперь нам нужно просто почленно перемножить всё и накопить суммы этих произведений в соответствующих ячейках массива. Тут понятно, что при перемножении членов со степенями `i` и `j` получается член степени `i + j`. Итого получается такой простой лаконичный код:

```
public static Polynom operator *(Polynom polynom1, Polynom polynom2)
{
    int[] coeffs = new int[polynom1.coefficients.Length + polynom2.coefficients.Length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < polynom1.coefficients.Length; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < polynom2.coefficients.Length; ++j)
            coeffs[i + j] += polynom1.coefficients[i] * polynom2.coefficients[j];
    return new Polynom(coeffs);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var p1 = new Polynom(1, 2, 3);
var p2 = new Polynom(2, 3, 4);
var p3 = p1 * p2;
Console.WriteLine(p1);
Console.WriteLine(p2);
Console.WriteLine(p3);
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 3x^2+2x+1
> 4x^2+3x+2
> 12x^4+17x^3+16x^2+7x+2
> ```

Comment: действительно, очень красивое и лаконичное решение.  спасибо Вам огромное!!